# Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution that is made up of 4 projects as shown in the screenshot [image: Screenshot of my solution layout]

The DbContext is inside NewKyc.Data project. The startup project is NewKyc

The ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs contains the following block

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
           dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
              .UseMySql(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MySQLConnection"], 
              new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(mysql_version[0], mysql_version[1], mysql_version[2])), b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("NewKyc")
```

To add migrations, I write the following

```
dotnet ef migrations add EntityRelationshipsReview --startup-project "../NewKyc.csproj" --context AppDbContext --verbose
```

and I get the following messages

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
> Switch: /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/NewKyc.csproj

And this

> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

Where am I getting it wrong?

It is a .NET Core 3.1 project upgraded to .NET 6

Comment: Try to add a "--project" argument with a path to the project with DbContext (`NewKyc.Data`)

Comment: @GoodboY I already tried that earlier even before posting the question and still got the same error message

Comment: Are you sure that the project is actually stored by this path? ` Project file does not exist. Switch: /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/NewKyc.csproj`

Answer (score 2):

Since you've upgraded from Net Core 3.1 to 6.0 it's possible your dotnet-ef CLI tool is out of date, you can update it globally, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-update), using the following command:

dotnet tool update -g dotnet-ef

Or locally:

dotnet tool update --local dotnet-ef

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you include the full paths to the folders as below:

```
dotnet-ef migrations add Testing -s C:\\NewKYCSolution\\NewKYC -c ApplicationDbContext -p C:\\NewKYCSolution\\NewKYC.Data --no-build
```

Try that.